# frola editor react doesn't reflect any changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, froala

I'm using this npm https://github.com/Zeyton-co/react-froala-editor, I've passed in some of the config like this

```
<FroalaEditor 
              base='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.3.4'
              value={this.state.editorValue}
              config={
                {shortcutsEnabled:['show', 'bold', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'indent', 'outdent', 'undo', 'redo', 'insertImage', 'createLink']}
              } 
            />
```

But I can't see the changes.

Comment: What 'change' do you expect to see exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There is another repo which is officially maintained by the Froala team and would be better to use that one: https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg. It also supports [two way bindings](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg#model).